# При запуске нового проекта на Django - открывается старый, уже удаленный

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Создал новый проект на Django,но при его запуске ( py manage.py runserver ) - запускается старый, уже удаленный, и приходится менять порт для запуска нового ( py manage.py runserver 8080 ). Времени с удаления того проекта прошло около месяца. Советовали посмотреть через утилиту, убит ли процесс, но и там я его не находил. Возможно не то искал. Необходимо что-то сделать, чтобы все новые проекты запускались на стандартном порту 8000

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Странная ситуация, но попробуйте выполнить следующий чек-лист и ответьте на вопрос:

1. Запускается именно старый проект, то-есть по адресу [localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000) открывается главная страница старого проекта ?
2. Или просто пишет, что порт занят ?

Проверьте, что проект вы запускали не в докере, выполните команду

> docker ps -a

Возможно вам придёться выполнить команду с использованием **sudo**, после выполнения команды убедитесь, что в консоли нет вывода с портами 8000

Так или иначе не достаточно вводных.

Comment: Старый проект запускается по адресу 127.0.0.1:8000,при изменении порта - все функционирует нормально.
Пользуюсь Вин, докер никак не могу проверить, но при запуске сервера, само собой, порт занимается